# How can I use P2 to create identically configured IDEs for multiple platforms?

Tags: eclipse, p2

I have an Eclipse installation each on machines running Linux, Windows and OSX, but they are all configured somewhat differently. For example the one on Linux has avr-eclipse, but the Mac one doesn't even have CDT.

What is the easiest way to make all these Eclipse installations consistent with each other, as far as installed features go? I guess I could go through it by hand, but surely there must be a way to use P2 to generate this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know eclipse itself doesn't provide an easy to make sure the multiple installation identify.

But you can try [P2 replication](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/p2-installation-replication) that is a plug-in to export your installation to file, then import it into other eclipse instances. You can install it via Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be just what I am looking for.